# nested $.ajax callback not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a project where I've got an object with two main methods, "save" and "relate", both hitting the server using jQuery ajax calls.

Both methods take callback functions as parameters, but only one of the callback methods is firing, even though looking in Chrome dev tools all of the Save/Relate posts are happening and returning valid data from the server.

Here are the three pieces I'm working with:

```
Entity.prototype.save = function(callback)
{
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Entity/Create',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        success: function (data){},
        error: function (xhr, status, err) { },
        complete: function (data)
        {
             console.log(self.get('_id') + ' saved.')
             if(callback)
                  callback(data.responseText);
        }
   });
 }

 Entity.prototype.relate = function(relatedEntityId, isRelate, callback)
 {
     var self = this;
     var action = isRelate ? 'Relate' : 'Unrelate';

     $.ajax({
         url: '/Entity/' + action,
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         data: JSON.stringify({ primaryEntityId: self._id.value, relatedEntityId: relatedEntityId }),
         done: function (data) { },
         fail: function (xhr, status, err) { },
         always: function (data)
         {
             console.log(self.get('_id') + 'related to ' + relatedEntityId);
             if(callback)
                 callback(data.responseText);
         }
     });
 }


 // from main code:

 entity.save(function (id) // this callback fires
 {
     // request is a previously saved 'entity'
     request.relate(id, true, function (id) // this callback does not
     {
         console.log('related callback completed.');
     });
 });
```

I'm not sure why the second callback (from request.relate) doesn't fire, when the $.ajax calls are set up in the same way (with the callback being fired in the 'complete' handler.

I'm testing in the latest version of Chrome (25.0.1364.172 m). Also have tested in Firefox 19 with same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`done` `fail` and `always` are not valid ajax properties, they are for deferred objects.

You need to use error/success/complete.

Comment: i feel dumb. thank you for pointing out my mistake. if I could vote myself down, I would.

Comment: mark his answer correct :)

Comment: i had to wait 5 minutes to do that. it was certainly correct.