# setInterval() firing but ajax update div content not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax, setinterval

In the `onDocumentReady(), $(function () {...})`, I have a line: `window.setInterval("readPluginCache();", 3000);`

The `readPluginCache()` method invokes an ajax call to retrieve and format replacement html for a named `$('#pluginCacheData')` element.

I can see in Chrome (F12) that the ajax start, complete and success events are being recorded every three seconds (as expected).

However, the new html isn't replacing the old html values...
I have a button on the page (as a backup) and it calls the `readPluginCache()` method; it works!

How do I make the `setInterval()` methodology to work?

```
function readPluginCache() {
    if (!isAuthorized) {
        addMessageError("Error: Unauthorized readCache attempt.");
        return false;
    }

    $('#pluginCacheData').hide();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: infoPageName + "/BriskPluginCacheInfoHtml",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (response) {
        $('#pluginCacheData').empty();
        $('#pluginCacheData').append(response.d);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, exception) {
        if (jqXHR.responseText.toLowerCase().indexOf('html') !== -1) {
            addMessageError("Internal Server Error: readPluginCache().     Please check the event log.");
        }
        else
            addMessageError("Error: " + jqXHR.responseJSON.Message);
        alert(exception);
    }).always(function () {
        $('#pluginCacheData').show();
    });

    return true;
}
```

Comment: We can't debug code that you haven't shown us

Comment: Rory, true... I was asking from a wider standpoint, I mean, what causes this behavior in general terms? I suspect it's a threading thing...

Comment: Please see my revised post... Thank you!

Comment: try replace setInterval to something like this -> `window.setInterval(readPluginCache, 3000);`

Comment: Rafael, I have just tried your suggestion and the results are the same...

Comment: I have also just noticed that the screen flickers when each 3-second event fires. Yet, the html remains unchanged...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15625286/8548193 maybe this answer can help you.

Comment: Per [link]https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ midpage: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it working; but I'm not sure why this works...
I have abstracted the original ajax call by encapsulating it another function called readAll(), so: window.setInterval(readAll, 3000). The readAll() calls three different ajax-based html/div modifying methods sequentially. I did this b/c there are other parts of the page that also need to dynamically update... It's a mystery to me why this works when one ajax call didn't.